# Remove time from NSDate object and save it in NSDate not in string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

There are lot of questions about date and time, but my question is a bit different.

Why `NSDate` comes with times added to it?
Why can not time be removed from `NSDate`? I can remove the time but it needs to be saved in String, Why it is not allowed to save it in `NSDate`?

Comment: where you want to store NSDate in SQLite or in local variable?

Comment: local NSDate and then will pass it to json. then it will be stored in oracle database

Comment: Format the date using NSDateFormatter as per the format you want, then store it to NSDate variable & then pass to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to remove TimeStamp from NSDate. NSDate is always packed with timestamp.

NSDate is based on the UTC time zone. If it is 1AM in US, it will be 12:30 PM in some other country and the date will be different. It will become trouble to get who entered when if different dates are there. So to make the date consistent timestamp-ing is required.

EDIT:

UTC update as suggested by Zaph :)
tiemstamp as suggested by Daij-Djan

Comment: `NSDate` is based on the UTC time zone. `NSLog()` displays the date formatted for the time zone of the computer. `NSDateFormatter` allows the timezone to be specified.

Answer (score 3):

`NSDate` actually stores a number of seconds from reference date (Jan 1, 2001). Everything rest are calendar calculations based on this amount of seconds. If you truncate time components and store result as 'NSDate' you will have different dates on different time zones.

You should consider using `NSDateFormatter` to convert `NSDate` values to string. Use:

```
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

to setup date formatter to ignore time.

Comment: just to add: NSDate is just a wrapper around an 'integer' there is no dedicated time component

Comment: Actually it is wrapper on double :)

Comment: I feared somebody would say that. Im aware that it is => typedef NSTimeInterval double. but the values after the , are always nil because a TIMESTAMP is always in full seconds. Why the used a double is beyond me btw.

Comment: @Daij-Djan: I cannot confirm that `NSDate` uses only integer values. `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]` returns double values with a fractional part.

Comment: @MartinR yes, sorry you are. for sub-second precision it does indeed sorry

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
func dayOf(date: NSDate) -> NSDate {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateBySettingHour(0, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions())!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A reusable way to solve this problem in **swift** is writing an extension on NSDate to trim the time off of the object.

```
import Foundation

extension NSDate {
  func trimTime() -> NSDate {
      let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
      let components = cal.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: self)
      return cal.dateFromComponents(components)!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSDate is a presentation way of time stamp, you can get different date with different timezone of the same NSDate object, so you cannot just save the "date" part of NSDate object, that's not the way NSDate works.

If you don't want time present in date string, just format it without time.

My suggestion is save time stamp in your database, if you need to find certain date, use a range query, that way you can deal with timezone problem.

Timezone function is hard to implement with date field.